# RowIterator Object Not Callable while using BigQuery + Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I am working on putting my Google BigQuery data into a pandas dataframe. I am successfully able to run the below code and print the result set.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from pandas.io import gbq

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('My Project Credentials.json')
project_id = 'essential-cairn-253818'
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=project_id)
query = client.query("""
SELECT  device.model as model
FROM     `my-table-name`
LIMIT 100
""")

results = query.result()
for row in results:
  print("{}".format(row.model))
```

However, I would like to use the pandas.io.gbq.read_gbq() functionality to put this into a dataframe. I add the next rows of code and I get stuck.

```
query2 = """
SELECT  device.model as model
FROM     `my-table-name`
LIMIT 100
"""
results_df = gbq.read_gbq(query2, project_id=project_id, private_key='My Project Credentials.json', dialect = 'standard')
```

This produces the error:

```
TypeError: 'RowIterator' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I am following the question seen here: [Live data from BigQuery into a Python DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265989/live-data-from-bigquery-into-a-python-dataframe)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider using the `pandas-gbq` package.  https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .  Your other option is loop through `results` (as you have done) and append each row to a list, then convert the list to a pandas df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with closing Spyder and restarting Python... something was going on unrelated to the code in this query. Very odd, but working now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too.

You could try pandas.read_gbq, seems a better choice.
Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_gbq.html

Also this other method seems less problematic: [How to integrate Bigquery & pandas](https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/how-to-integrate-bigquery-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the official method `query_job.result().to_dataframe()`?

My code is:

```
results = query_job.result()
df = results.to_dataframe()
df.to_csv('demo1.csv',index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep = ',')
```

Comment: I recommend against answers in the shape of a rhetoric question, it risks being misunderstood as a question where an answer should be.

Comment: ```query_job.to_dataframe()```  without the ```.results()``` part seems to give the same output as well